# Implementing a 3x3 image grid using Django

Tags: python, html, django, bootstrap-4

I am trying to implement a 3x3 grid in Django.

**Further notes:**

- Within each grid square I should be able to place images sourced directly from my computer.
- The images should fit each grid square entirely.

What is the best approach to implement such specifications?

An example of what I am trying to accomplish:

[image: Image Grid]

Comment: First, you can try reading about jinja templates. using these, you can generate your output html. All django will help you here, is locate the files required and pass them to jinja template.

Comment: This doesnt seem like a django question the issue relates to how you present the content in you html. You have tagged bootstrap 4, so utilise the row and columns in bootstraps framework to make a 3 by 3 grid

Comment: Make a table with three rows and three columns, and put an `<img>` tag in each of the nine cells.